# Rounded Image with curved caption using css3

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a rounded image with curved caption container inside the image. How it can be done using html5, css3. Please check the image to get better picture. If there is any example available please share it.

[Sample Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox6l9c4cpuxh0o6/rounde_image_caption.JPG)

Comment: have you tried anything? Please include the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want this:
[image]

check this link: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BRj3P/8/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="imgContainer">

        <img src=""/>
        <div></div>

    </div>
</div>
```